# php - help converting timestamp string to readable time format

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I have a record called `Time` with the following date string: `20100902040003` in the input file.

I need some php help to convert this to something more readable such as this format: `2010-09-02 04:00:03`
and would like to format it as I print out the table data.

Answer (score 10):

```
$timestamp = "20100902040003";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($timestamp)); // output: 2010-09-02 04:00:03
```

Comment: @downvoter: It is giving result as mentioned in question. Will you explain it in detail ?

Comment: Changed my -1 to +1 since I misread. I missed out the `strtotime()` call.

Comment: @codaaddict because the function `strtotime` converts it to a timestamp

Comment: it seems silly to exercise all the date-parsing and date-formatting code just to splice some punctuation into a string.

Answer (score 2):

Since the timestamp is not a unix timestamp, you have to use `substr()`

```
$timestamp = "20100902040003";

$year = substr($timestamp, 0, 3);
$month = substr($timestamp, 4, 5);
$day = substr($timestamp, 6, 7);
$hour = substr($timestamp, 8, 9);
$minute = substr($timestamp, 10, 11);
$second = substr($timestamp, 12, 13);
```

Then you arrange that using `sprintf()`

```
$formatted_timestamp = sprintf('%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s', $year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second);
```

Comment: thanks. would I put this function in my foreach statement as I dynamically create the row? thanks.

Comment: I fixed the format since G will print the hour without leading zero, you have to use H instead.

You could put the function when you create the array, or when you print it out, both works.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure that all records in your input file have the format `YYYYMMDDHHmmss`, you could try to split the string yourself and then using `date()` in conjunction with `mktime()` to generate a meaningful date format.

Comment: thanks. yes, all the records have that exact same format. can you show me an example?

Comment: strtotime() does understand ISO 8601 timestamps such as "20100902040003"

Comment: I think nohat's solution is better since it completely skips the `date` and `mktime` functions.

Comment: @nohat: I eventually realized, and took that statement off my answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Since your data is already in the right format, it just needs some punctuation, so you can use a regular expression, rather than the date-parsing and date-formatting functions.

```
$timestamp = "20100902040003";
preg_replace('/(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/', 
             '\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6', $timestamp)
```

yields:

```
2010-09-02 04:00:03
```